# An asymptotic approximation of stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: analysis, number-theory, approximation, infinity, stirling-numbers

How can one prove that an asymptotic approximation of stirling numbers of the second kind S(n,k) is k^n/k!, k is fixed and n goes to infinity .I found this in wikipedia

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).